# Is it fine if I use "define A B" rather than "define A as B"?

Tags: meaning

The textbook I have been reading uses the sentence:

"As in the discussion of state augmentation in Section 1.4, it is intuitively clear that we should define a new system whose state at time *k* is the set of all variables the knowledge of which can be of benefit to the controller when making the *k*th decision."

Getting rid of some trivial parts of the sentence, we get

"We should define a new system whose state at time *k* is the set of all variables the knowledge of which can be of benefit to the controller when making the *k*th decision."

Since "whose state at time *k* is the set of all variables" is just the modifier to "a new system", and since "of which can be of benefit to the controller when making the *k*th decision" is also the modifier to "the knowledge", we can reduce the sentence to

"We should define a new system the knowledge."

---

Now, I was wondering why the author did not write "We should define a new system as the knowledge."

Is the phrase of "define A B" equivalent to one of "define A as B"?

Comment: In your massive pruning of this sentence, you've kept "knowledge" but deleted the object of that knowledge, "variables".  As a result, the pruned sentence has lost the meaning of the original and has become ungrammatical.  The original sentence did not propose "defining a new system as knowledge", but that would at least be grammatical; "defining a new system the knowledge" is not grammatical.

Comment: @AndreasBlass You mean, is it wrong?? I understood that we should define a new system (whose state at time k is the set of all variables) the knowledge (of which can be of benefit to the controller) when making the kth decision, didn't it?

Comment: My understanding of the original sentence is that "the knowledge of which can be of benefit to the controller when making the *k*th decision" modifies "variables".  Any variable whose value is useful for the *k*th decision should be included in the state at time *k*.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Ah-hah you mean it is appositive of variables. Good thank you very much

Comment: I don't see any apposition to "variables" here.  The long phrase that I quoted in my previous comment, "the knowledge ... decision," is a relative clause, in whose relative pronoun "which" has "variables" as its antecedent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> we can reduce the sentence to
>
> "We should define a new system the knowledge."

No, that's wrong. You can reduce the original sentence to three statements:

1. We should define a new system;
2. The *state* of the system (*not* the system itself) will be a set of variables;
3. The variables included in the set will be those that the controller can use in making a decision.

> Is the phrase of "define A B" equivalent to one of "define A as B"?

No.

Answer (score 1):

In geometry, for instance, a line AB would be a line from A to B, and the  question would be to define that line. This would not be the same as defining A in relation to B.